# Didn't get Passport back from UKVI scanning hub, New York

Tags: visas, usa, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I sent all my documents to NY.

I did it under Priority Visa. Sent it on 20th May.

I received my supporting documents back but didnt get my passport or decision letter. What's going on?

Comment: How long ago did you submit all your documents?

Comment: I did it under Priority Visa. Sent it on 20th May.

Comment: My understanding is that they send the documents separate from passports

Comment: Really? Everyone on reddit is saying that they got it together @Midavalo

Comment: What did UKVI say when you asked them?

Comment: Very vague and unhelpful. They said that there are million reasons why they might have not returned your passport.